# Importing Custom Object to Commerce Cloud

Tags: custom-object, marketing-cloud-connect, commerce-cloud

I've been following the instructions on the SFMC Connector repository, and one of those instructions says to "Import the metadata, custom objects, and jobs definitions into your B2C Commerce environment."

I've managed to import the Custom Object Type definitions without any issue, but once I try to import one of the custom objects I get the following error "ERROR [2|85] cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'custom-objects'."

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: The issue was the file being uploaded on the wrong place, and trying to import it on the wrong place as well.